# Javascript Regular Expression to replace only multiple occurrences with that substitute

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to replace multiple spaces with as many `'&nbsp;'` as there are spaces. However, I do not want to replace single spaces.

```
let string = 'The quick  brown fox   jumped over    a lazy      dog';
```

My desired output is

```
"The quick&nbsp;&nbsp;brown fox&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;jumped over&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;a lazy&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;dog"
```

I am able to do this by `string.replace(/(\S)( )(\S)/g, "$1~$3").replace(/ /g, '&nbsp;').replace(/~/g, ' ');`. But this requires the string to be scanned through three replace statements. I am replacing single spaces with ~, then all spaces with nbsp; and then finally reverting ~ to single spaces.
Is there an easier way of doing this by just one scan?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using a browser that supports lookbehinds, you can use them to replace a space which is either preceded or followed by another space with `&nbsp;` using this regex:

```
(?<= ) | (?= )
```

[Demo on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/bqtEmN/1/)

```js
let string = 'The quick  brown fox   jumped over    a lazy      dog';

console.log(string.replace(/(?<= ) | (?= )/g, '&nbsp;'));
```

If your browser doesn't support lookbehinds, you can use a callback to replace a sequence of 2 or more spaces with a string of `&nbsp;` of the same length:

```js
let string = 'The quick  brown fox   jumped over    a lazy      dog';

console.log(string.replace(/ {2,}/g, (m) => '&nbsp;'.repeat(m.length)));
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be matching on `[ ]{2,}`, and then replacing the spaces there with `&nbsp;`.  A regex function callback comes in handy here:

```js
var string = 'The quick  brown fox   jumped over    a lazy      dog';
var output = string.replace(/[ ]{2,}/g, function(match, contents, offset, string)
    {
        return match.replace(/[ ]/g, '&nbsp;');
    }
);
console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) and [`join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) together.

```js
let string = 'The quick  brown fox   jumped over    a lazy      dog';
const trimmedString = string.split("  ").join("&nbsp;")
console.log(trimmedString)
```